# Size of basis of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ s.t whenever $T_1$ and $T_2$ agree on $A$, we require $T_1=T_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^4$ be such that whenever $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ s.t $T_1(x)=T_2(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$, then $T_1=T_2$ What is number of elements in the basis of $A$?

The options are:

- at least $7$
- exactly $4$
- at least $4$
- at most $7$

I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

First note that $T_1$ and $T_2$ agree on $A$ if and only if $T_1$ and $T_2$ agree on span$(A)$.

If $A$ contains less than $4$ elements, this means $\dim(\text{span}(A))\leq 3$, thus $\text{span}(A)$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then we can easily construct two linear maps such that they agree on $\text{span}(A)$ but are not equal everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Thus $A$ must contain at least $4$ elements.

Secondly, it's possible that $A$ contains more than $7$ elements, for example simply choose $A=\mathbb{R}^4$. Thus the options "at most $7$ elements and "exactly $4$ elements" are false.

Lastly $A$ does not need to contain more than $7$ elements, an example is $A=\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ which is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.